Using generics in the typing to describe parameters as concrete classes and as instances of those classes
Since I have to validate class attributes (comparables) constantly, it seems sensible to put this into a more or less universal descriptor that should validate the type of argument being set and the range of values ​​if that is acceptable.
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound=type)
Instance = TypeVar("Instance", bound=T) # ???

class TypeAndValueValidator:
    def __init__(
        self,
        type_: T = None,
        start_value=None,
        end_value=None,
        include_start: bool = True,
        include_end: bool = True,
    ):
        self.type = type_
        self.start_value = start_value
        self.end_value = end_value
        self.include_start = include_start
        self.include_end = include_end

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        # ...

    def __get__(self, obj, obj_type=None):
        # ...

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        # ...

How to express it:

The type_ attribute is a class.

The start_value and end_value are instances of the class specified in the type_ attribute.


Accordingly - then I can specify type constraints for the parameters of the methods set_name, get, set, etc.
I tried to figure this out using the typing documentation, but it remained unclear to me.

You don't need the second typevar. You can do: type_: Type[T] | None = None, start_value: T | None = None, end_value: T | None = None,, where Type[T] is a class which creates instances of T

It also might make sense to create a secondary class for the value ranges which implements __contains__. Then your validation can do: if obj in self.range

Why are you giving type_ a default value of None? It seems like that should be a required argument.

yes, regarding type_ - correct comment, thank you
